# How can I get User-Scoped Credentials (Personal Credentials) in withCredentials

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I get the ERROR: Build failed with `org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.CredentialNotFoundException` when I try to use the User-Scoped Credentials (the ones, defined for particular user - not in the Jenkins -> Credentials configuration

I want to create a parametrized build, where a user will be able to choose the credentials defined by the users. Something like:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: params.customUser, usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
        //do sth with USERNAME & PASSWORD
}
```

`params.customUser` - is the one chosen by the user from dropdown list while running the build

Answer (score 4):

This is not supported at the moment. Here are several open issues to support user-scoped credentials:

- [JENKINS-38963 - User-scoped credentials cannot be looked up in pipeline](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38963)
- [JENKINS-47699 - Cannot use user-scoped credentials from pipeline input step parameters](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47699)
- [JENKINS-44772 - User Scoped credentials are not used by the "withCredentials" pipeline step](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44772)

Comment: On 2019-08-27 20:53 https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47699 was marked resolved.
As of 2023-06-22 the other two are still open.

Answer (score 0):

Instead why can we store the credentials in Jenkins with a meaningful Credential ID for each, and the Job would have an extensible-choice-parameter(drop-down) where we can list all the CredentialID in the drop. The user can select from the drop down which can easily be accessed in the pipeline.

Thanks,

Comment: This would be the fastest and easiest solution. Unfortunately, due to some client Jenkins-admin politics - this is not possible.

Comment: So, are you using enterprise Jenkins version or open source one?

Comment: The original request by @ChrisJaga already specifies that they are using a drop down list. If you believe that "extensible-choice-parameter" can solve the problem, please provide more details.

Answer (score -3):

Use
`credentialsId: 'customUser'` instead of
`credentialsId: params.customUser`, as per the [Cloudbees guide](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/pipelines/user-scoped-creds)

Comment: `params.customUser` is a parameter in the job used to SELECT the credential id. This answer will not solve that problem. Indeed, it will remove the ability of the invoker to select the credential and fix it to one named 'customUser' which defeats the purpose of the question.